# How to return CLOB datatype as output Parameter in Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: xml, oracle, stored-procedures, clob

I want to return an output param of CLOB datatype(XML data) from an oracle stored procedure.

My procedure looks like this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE myProcedure
(
  myParam1 IN NUMBER 
 ,myParam2 IN NUMBER 
 ,myParam3 OUT CLOB 
) AS  
   xml_bits CLOB;
BEGIN

 select  xmldataColumn into xml_bits 
 from myTable WHERE id = myParam1 AND SESSION_ID = myParam2;

  IMPCPM_XML := xml_bits;
END myProcedure;
```

I compiled this and when i try to execute, it is giving me the following error.

```
exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

How do I return a big xmldata as an out param?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error isn't related to returning CLOB values via an OUT parameter.  It simply says that your SELECT query returned more than one row.  To use `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM`, the query must return precisely one row, or you will get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with returning a `CLOB` value. It is that the query:

```
select  xmldataColumn into xml_bits 
from myTable WHERE id = myParam1 AND SESSION_ID = myParam2;
```

Returns more than one row and using `SELECT ... INTO ...` requires that the query returns only a single row.

You could add a filter for `ROWNUM = 1`:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE myProcedure
(
  myParam1 IN NUMBER 
 ,myParam2 IN NUMBER 
 ,myParam3 OUT CLOB 
) AS  xml_bits CLOB;
BEGIN
  select xmldataColumn
  into   xml_bits 
  from   myTable
  WHERE  id = myParam1
  AND    SESSION_ID = myParam2
  AND    ROWNUM = 1;
END myProcedure;
/
```

Or you could handle the exception:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE myProcedure
(
  myParam1 IN NUMBER 
 ,myParam2 IN NUMBER 
 ,myParam3 OUT CLOB 
) AS  xml_bits CLOB;
BEGIN
  select xmldataColumn
  into   xml_bits 
  from   myTable
  WHERE  id = myParam1
  AND    SESSION_ID = myParam2;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    xml_bits := NULL;
END myProcedure;
/
```